# What happened here? Wrong closure reason?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I voted to migrate this question to Super User (Eg: Vote-to-close -> This question is off topic -> This question belongs to a another site in the stack exchange network -> This question belongs to Super User), and now it tells me that I voted it to close because of "unclear what you are asking".
[T-Mobile WWAN IP address is DoD Network Information Center?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/116659/t-mobile-wwan-ip-address-is-dod-network-information-center/116661#116661)

What really happened? Why was the reason on my vote changed?

Comment: The question is why it says that I voted it for being unclear, when I voted it for being off-topic? And IMHO I don't think its unclear, its pretty clear its the 21.x.x.x IP that is DoD and since DoD is a US corporation, its clear that he queried ARIN whois database.

Comment: @TildalWave Sent a feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276607/users-should-be-allowed-to-cast-conditional-close-votes